# im using jquery/ajax for login. Sending works and server side returns to log in, but this fails

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have created a login system with PHP, however, i also added two factor authentication. I wanted to log in without having to refresh the page so it looks better when asking for the 2FA code

The way i have done this is by sending the username and password via ajax. my php script then checks this and then it would echo login or error

Here's my javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'inc/auth.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                if (data === 'login') {
                    window.location = '/user-page.php';
                }
                else {
                    alert('Invalid Credentials');
                }
            },
        });
    });
});
```

This works fine, when i alert the data i get 'login' (without quotes, obviously) however it doesn't send me to user-page.php, instead, it gives me the invalid credentials alert. Despite the php page returning login, javascript is like "nope!"
What am i doing wrong?
Here's my form

```
<form class="form" id="login-form" name="login-form" method="post" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Gebruikersnaam</label>
    <input type="username" class="form-control" id="gebruikersnaam" name="gebruikersnaam" placeholder="gebruikersnaam" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Wachtwoord</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="wachtwoord" name="wachtwoord" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="help-block text-right"><a href="">Forget the password ?</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Sign in</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I run the javascript from this page via `<script src="auth.js"></script>`. I also tried putting it directly inside script tags witch failed too.

Comment: is data a string with the name login?

Comment: where is `exampleInputEmail2` and `exampleInputPassword2` ?

Comment: second thing besides this issue, you have an security problem here aswell, and that problem is called CSFR attack, you can google it for more information

Comment: where is  your server side script

Comment: ( CSFR attack doesn't exist but CSRF attack does)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for testing purpose
I believe your **dataType** should be either **html** or **json**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'inc/auth.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                if (data == 'login') {
                    window.location = '/user-page.php';
                }
                if (data == 'failed') {
                    alert('Invalid Credentials');
                }

            },
        });
    });
});
```

In absence of your server logic
Your php inc/auth.php FOR Testing purpose

```
//$gebruikersnaam= $_POST['gebruikersnaam'];
//$wachtwoord= $_POST['wachtwoord'];


$gebruikersnaam= 'nancy';
$wachtwoord= 'nancy123';

if($gebruikersnaam=='nancy' && $wachtwoord=='nancy123')
{
    echo "login";
}
else
{
    echo "failed";
}
```

As for CSRF attack mentioned by SO Scholar in the comment. you will need to generate something like md5 token that will be stored in a session. you will now send it with each request eg. in a hidden form input and verify that it matches the one on the server side. if match allow login otherwise trigger impersonation

**Updates**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'inc/auth.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data)
            {
                alert(data);
                if (data.login == 'success') {
                    window.location = '/user-page.php';
                }
                if (data.login == 'failed') {
                    alert('Invalid Credentials');
                }

            },
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$gebruikersnaam= 'nancy';
$wachtwoord= 'nancy123';

if($gebruikersnaam=='nancy' && $wachtwoord=='nancy123')
{
    $return_arr = array('login'=>'success');
}
else
{
    $return_arr = array('login'=>'failed');
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

Comment: setting to JSON throws an error, text/html work ok. im 100% sure my php backend works as it echoes back whatever i set the login echo message to. If i made it "potato" for example, the javascript data variable would read back "potato" comparing data to potato in this case still doesn't do anything.
 console.log(data) returns potato. if (data == 'potato') doesn't work

Comment: @MGSneaky for JSON you have to use .serializeArray() , but you will have to change the php part

Comment: @MGSneaky see my updated part of the answer for json code

Comment: i dont want to use json for this, this should work fine without right?

Comment: yes. i have given you two samples. make your choice